# Best option to run much android emulator instances

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I am testing my multiplayer game on android and would like to test as many players as possible at once. I need to run multiple instances of android parallel, really 30+. So far I have been using nox emulator with minimal performance but I am having problems with its stability etc. What will be the best choice? The requirement is minimum android 6.0 and appium support (simple rooting and proxy running are welcome). I was considering: android-x86 + virtualbox, android-x86 + docker, some hyper-v based emulator, maybe some form of headless?

Answer (score 0):

The best choice is to move your multiplayer testings on API level: faster and reliable.
You can leave a single session on mobile device just in case you want to collect performance metrics for multiplayer or make any e2e-specific checks, but running multiple devices won't give any benefit.

I assume you can create multiple virtual session via API and single one on device. Then just focus on running verification on that device.